# Textbox Value Range VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

How can set a range for the numbers in VB.NET . e.g

```
If val(textbox1.text = 100 to 200) then 
// messagebox.show("The number is between 100 and 200")
end if
```

What should I put instead of "to" to get it working ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check individually:

```
Dim value = val(textbox1.text)
If (value >= 100 And value <= 200) Then 
    ' ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Reed Copsey is correct, but I always favor short-circuiting the condition with `AndAlso`

```
If (value >= 100 AndAlso value <= 200) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be the time for you to know about `<` and `>` operators.

```
If (value > 99 And value < 201) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

For something short like this, a simple IF would look better. But if you have multiple checks for multiple ranges, a `Select Case` works better:

```
    Select Case  Val(textbox1.Text)
        Case 100 To 200
            ' Number between 100 and 200 inclusive
        Case Else
            ' anything else
    End Select
```